# Integrating the Terraform Plan output into Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, terraform, devops

I have written a declarative pipeline using a Jenkinsfile at the root of the repo. The pipeline is very simple. it dose a `terraform plan` and a `terraform apply`

Is it possible to take the output of the `terraform plan` display it in the Jenkins GUI and then ask of an input for the user if they would like to go ahead with the `terraform apply`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never tried this but Jenkins does have an [input step](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-input-step/) as part of the pipeline plugin.

In addition, terraform allows you [to store the output of a plan](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/plan.html#out-path), and then to use that saved output when running `terraform apply`. The [`-auto-approve` flag](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/apply.html#auto-approve) means you can skip the need for user input on the apply.

I don't think it is possible to ask the user for the input in the middle of the `terraform apply`, because the input step is a step.

So I think the pipeline would have to look something like the following:

```
pipeline {
    agent { ... }
    stages {
        stage('build') {
            steps {
                sh 'terraform plan -out=./my-plan'
                input message: "Apply plan?"
                sh 'terraform apply -auto-approve ./my-plan' 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If the infrastructure is changed between the plan and the apply then there would be problems.

Comment: If the infrastructure changes between the plan and the apply then the apply fails safely before doing anything as part of the refresh (while the state is locked) so that should be fine.

Comment: the answer given by @theonlyra is correct. I am adding the following link as it gives a complete solution in case this its useful to other people that have the same question: [Terraform Pipeline using Jenkins](https://medium.com/@devopslearning/100-days-of-devops-day-34-terraform-pipeline-using-jenkins-a3d81975730f)